# Restart an application as administrator

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

Hi i have this search application that runs on my server. it indexes web pages and provides a search server for me to query the results. Kinda like GSA but free.

i have to restart the search server occasionally. the problem is this search server is started by admin account(it gets started with task scheduler). i can remote into it with my own account and start the search server. but as soon as i log out, the search server would close. i need to keep the search server running indefinitely.

what is the best way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try having an admin create a Windows service for it using the sc command.  Then the service manager mechanisms for restarting the process and whatnot would be available.  Have a look [**here**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192).

Comment: damn good stuff